# How do I take the leading consonants an move them to the end of the string?

Tags: java, jcreator

The Code I am doing is, If the word starts with a consonant,it moves all leading consonats to the end of the word and adds "ay". For example "bring" to "ingbray".

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, as a one-time new-user welcome bonus, and given its simple nature, I have answered your question. In future, please show your attempt in the question as per [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to match leading consonants:

```
String pigLatin = str.replaceAll("(?i)(^[^aeiou]+)(.*)", "$2$1ay");
```

Breaking this down:

- `(?i)` = ignore case
- `[^aeiou]` = any non-vowel
- `[^aeiou]+` = 1 or more non-vowels (”greedy” match - ie as many as possible)
- `(^[^aeiou]+)` = 1 or more non-vowels anchored to start, captured as group 1
- `(.*)` any other characters, captured as group 2

And the replacement:

- `$2` group 2
- `$1` group 1
- `ay` literal "ay"